# Algorithm for predictably splitting data structures no matter the order it's built

Tags: algorithm, solr, b-tree

The requirements:

I'm adding a feature to a program that builds Solr index's.  The system is multi-threaded, so the search entries will be created in a random order every time.  The Solr index's also need to be split into multiple files because if a user tries to upload one big file, the server can run out of memory.

The problem:

In order to keep the system reliable and make things easier overall, the resulting Solr index files need to be the same no matter what order they're processed in.  The indices need to be balanced across the files (or close enough to balanced), and have a maximum amount of entries.  If the files go beyond the maximum amount of entries, they need to be split.  These files will also be updated across runs, so entries will be added, removed, and changed.

What's needed:

I'm looking for an algorithm that can be adopted for these requirements.  I think I need some kind of B-tree, but I don't know about any B-tree variants that fits around this particular set of requirements.

Is there an algorithm or data structure out there that can help with these requirements?

Comment: What does "The Solr index files need to be the same" mean? Do you mean that regardless of the order they're processed, the files have to be identical? Or that the contents of the file, once read and processed, have to create the same result?

Comment: The default Lucene index files are append only, so if you're adding stuff in a different order, you'll get different files (the internal docid will be different as well). You can create your own codec to serialize and deserialize content yourself. Could you expand on _why_ you have these requirements? Are you building the Lucene index yourself outside of Solr, and how are you building it? Can you create a structure on disk and in memory and then serialize that structure in sequence to Lucene? Having a binary tree in each thread would work in that case, and then merge that to disk.

Comment: By "The Solr index files need to be the same", I mean the files themselves have to be identical.  These requirements are to prove the reliability and integrity of the program.  I don't know how the Solr indexes are being created because we're not that far into planning.  However, I can say that these files are going to be in JSON format.  We can create structures on disk and in memory however we want, just as long as the resulting files are consistent.

Comment: I think there is some confusion about the Lucene Index here and the question overall does not make much sense from  a Lucene/Solr perspective.
An application should rely on how Lucene manages the index segments and how it merges them.
I encourage to explore the deeps of the merge policy if you really want to know more about how the Lucene segments are merged.
Do you want to set up a cluster ? and route documents ? and replicate the index across ?
It is not clear though , could SolrCloudp[1] help ?
[1] https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/solrcloud.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a UUID based on contents.  For splitting the file, send each item to a bucket based on the range that the UUID falls in.  No matter what order you get items, this will reliably send it to buckets with relatively even sizes, and the unique index will guarantee that the result comes out the same.

See https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey for more detailed advice, and https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LargeIndexes for other useful tips.